# Rviz tf error: unknown reason for transform failure

Tags: rviz, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everybody!
My OS: Ubuntu 10.04

My TF configure: /map -> /odom -> /base_link -> /base_scan.
[image: image description]

While the TF seems not problem, there is still an fatal error at RVIZ. RVIZ show an error about laser scan: unknown reason for transform failure. I'm confuse, so I need your help. I'm appreciate for any hints.

[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10284/rviz-tf-error:-unknown-reason-for-transform-failure/) by [gong](https://answers.ros.org/users/551/gong/) on ROS Answers with karma: 164 on 2011-06-16

Post score: 6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How are you publishing the /scan topic?

It has to have the frame_id /base_scan set.
Also it should have a current timestamp (i.e. corresponding to those in the rviz machine), this might be a problem with multiple computers.

Do you see a scan, if you set the fixed_frame in rviz to the frame_id of the scan?

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2011-06-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gong](https://answers.ros.org/users/551/gong/) on 2011-06-16**:
In my scan topic, I provide frame_id of scan to be "base_scan".  Also, I'm setting the header.stamp of scan message to be current time as timestamp.

**Comment by [gong](https://answers.ros.org/users/551/gong/) on 2011-06-16**:
when I set /base_scan to be fixed frame in RVIZ, the fatal error is gone.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had the same problem; no laser data is shown in rviz unless the laser's frame is set as the fixed frame.

I found a thread on the ros-users list that suggested it had to do with the time_increment field being too large. I noticed there is an error in the LMS1xx package I'm using as a driver for the laser. The fields time_increment and scan_time are ten times as high as they are supposed to be.

I think this was the cause of the error message. What's annoying is that it took 20-30 minutes after I fixed this for it to actually start working. I don't know why it didn't start working immediately. It's possible I restarted rviz at that stage, or managed to reset its laser module. I sure didn't change anything else, at least.

Here's the list thread I mentioned:
http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.science.robotics.ros.user/5192

---

Originally posted by [raahlb](https://answers.ros.org/users/966/raahlb/) with karma: 317 on 2011-09-20

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Markus Bader](https://answers.ros.org/users/390/markus-bader/) on 2014-07-22**:
Setting the time_increment to zero solved my problem.

**Comment by [AlexM](https://answers.ros.org/users/41877/alexm/) on 2019-07-08**:
For other people trying to make YDLIDAR work -- there's a bug in their ROS package which results in the same issue, and an open PR for it -- https://github.com/EAIBOT/ydlidar/pull/19/files.